# No compiler errors, but there is a bug somewhere

Tags: c, loops

I compiled with "gcc -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -o  ". I only get 2 errors when I compile, and here they are:

```
easter_eggs.c: In function ‘main’:
easter_eggs.c:23:18: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
    if (prompt == 'egg1')
                  ^
easter_eggs.c:23:4: warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
    if (prompt == 'egg1')
```

when I run the program and hit S, it displays the top 2 printf statements 2 times each. If I type anything and press enter nothing happens it just goes back to the prompt. Even if I type egg1, it still goes back to prompt. Here is the source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char first_option;
    char prompt[16];

    system("clear");
    system("toilet -f future -F gay Easter Eggs");
    printf("\nFind all the easter eggs and you win. Simple enough.\n");
    printf("Hit S to start and Q to quit\n");
    scanf("%c", &first_option);

    if (first_option == 's')
    {
        while (1)
        {
            printf("To exit hit Ctrl + C\n");
            printf("You must find all easter eggs simply by typing stuff in the prompt below: \n");
            memset(prompt, 0, sizeof(prompt));
            scanf("%16s", prompt);
            getchar();
            if (!strcmp(prompt, "egg1"))
            {
                printf("Found 1\n");
            }
        }
    }

    if (first_option == "q")
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Invalid input. Press Enter to continue\n");
        getchar();
        main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit 1: I have edited the source

Edit 2: Changed the source again. This time I use strcmp() to compare the strings, not ==

Last Edit: I managed to make it work. Also updated the source so that it works. Thx to all for being patient with me. Havn't slept in idk how many days. :/

Comment: You really need to check the result of `scanf`. If it returns `0` then your char will contain a garbage value.  It will be `0` if you didn't type in `>` before your input.

Comment: Note: be sure to use `"%15s"` with `char prompt[16]`.

Comment: Do not destructively edit your post.  Maybe append information changes.  As the post stands now, the below answers about "cannot use == operator to compare strings" now do not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Read more about C programming. You are confused about char and strings.

If you want to read a word as a a string of at most 16 bytes with a terminating null byte, use e.g.

```
  char prompt[16];
  memset (prompt, 0, sizeof(prompt));
  if (scanf("%15s", prompt)<1) return;
  if (!strcmp(prompt, "egg1")) {
     /// found
```

Also, you are right to compile with `-Wall`. But compile also with debugging information and extra warnings:

```
  gcc -Wall -Wextra -g easter_eggs.c -o easter_eggs
```

and [learn](http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html) how to **use the `gdb` debugger**.

Read also the man pages (type `man man` in your Linux terminal) of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) & [strcmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html)

Comment: Basile: I modified my code using your example, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Please use the `gdb` debugger. Don't expect us to debug your code. You need to learn.

Comment: Your `scanf` contains a `>` but mine don't.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare a char variable, you have to compare it with a char.

As the compiler told you, you have a multi-character here.

strcmp() will help you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other comments, Read C. Below are some suggestions

1. To store string in C, You must use `char[]` or `char *` after allocating memory.
2. You cannot use `==` operator to compare strings. Use `strcmp()` instead.